# (Nearly) empty JTable code

Tags: java, jtable, columnheader

I am wanting to add a blank table with headers to a miniature program I am working on. Obviously this is because part of the program's purpose is to add information to the table. I need the column's to have headers which I have  read up on how to do but I am unable to figure out how to define a table without coding in content.

```
    String[] ColumnNames = {"1column", "2column", "3column"};
/*
*
*/
        EmptyTable = new JTable((???),ColumnNames);
        add(EmptyTable);
```

This is the code I currently have. The (???) is there because I am strongly suspecting the missing code I cannot find is to belong in that spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of [that JTable constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) takes an `Object[][]`, expected to be the initial table model.

```
emptyTable = new JTable(new Object[ColumnNames.length][], columnNames);
```

As a side note, variables should be named with camelCase, as is dictated by Java conventions (i.e. EmptyTable should be emptyTable, ColumnNames should be columnNames).